# Calculation on fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I need to perform some calculations on some numeric fields when the user inputs a number. I made the HTML for the form, and below I have this JavaScript code so far but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // define the variables for fields
  var child1 = $('pdb-male').val();
  var child2 = $('pdb-female').val();
  var child3 = $('pdb-unknown_sex').val();

  var value = child1 + child2 + child3;

  var result = $('pdb-number');

  // set listener on male field
  child1.on('keyup', function() {

    // do the calculation and output the result on the field
    result.val(value);
  });

  // set listener on female field    
  child2.on('keyup', function() {

    // do the calculation and output the result on the field
    result.val(value);
  });

  // set listener on unknown_sex field    
  child3.on('keyup', function() {

    // do the calculation and output the result on the field
    result.val(value);
  });

  // set the trigger on fields 
  child1.trigger('keyup');
  child2.trigger('keyup');
  child3.trigger('keyup');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML and CSS to your snippet.

Comment: Move the `var child1 = $('pdb-male').val();
  var child2 = $('pdb-female').val();
  var child3 = $('pdb-unknown_sex').val();` inside the event handlers and convert the values to numbers

Comment: Hi @mplungjan and thanks for your reply. How do I convert them to numbers?

Comment: Please, to help other S.O. members, put a complete sample of your code, with the HTML markup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need a # in front of each selector assuming they are IDs
- move the var declarations inside the event handler
- convert the values to numbers.
- Reuse the event handler
- Use a class - then it is even simpler:

```js
$(function() {
 $(".person").on("input", function() {      
    var total = 0;
    $(".person").each(function() { total += +this.value })
    $('#pdb-number').val(total); 
  }).trigger("input")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Male:<input class="person" type="text" id="pdb-male" value="" /><br/> 
Female: <input class="person" type="text" id="pdb-female" value="" /><br/> 
Unknown: <input class="person" type="text" id="pdb-unknown_sex" value="" /><br/>
Total: <input type="text" readonly id="pdb-number" />
```

Comment: Please look at the new version - it is even better

Comment: @mplungjan, i don't understand why you have added trigger('input')

Comment: Because OP had. To run the script on load in case the fields already had a value